# Parse.com > Query Constraints > based on user Pointer

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class called AccountData and I would like to return all rows that relate to a particular user. In the class I have a Pointer to the User table which contains their "ObjectId"

I have tried with the following call to the API:

```
string url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AccountData?" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("where={\"user\":\"fvJ8jPjyjx\"}");
```

where the fvJ8jPjyjx is the ObjectId of the user I want rows relating to...

The api doesn't throw any errors just returns:

```
{"results":[]}
```

I have also tried it using a "User Object" as follows:

```
public class AccountDataUser
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public string className { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
}
```

building the object as follows:

```
AccountDataUser user = new AccountDataUser();
user.__type = "Pointer";
user.className = "_User";
user.objectId = objectId;
string jsonUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

but this throws an api error.

Can anyone help me return the rows relating to a "user" please?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Based on Ryans feedback I have reverted to trying to send an object...

This is what is being sent:

```
GET https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AccountData?where%3D%7B%22user%22%3A%22%7B%22__type%22%3A%22Pointer%22%2C%22className%22%3A%22_User%22%2C%22objectId%22%3A%22fvJ8jPjyjx%22%7D%22%7D HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxx
X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxxx
Host: api.parse.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The url is built with this line of code:

```
ParseModel.AccountDataUser user = new ParseModel.AccountDataUser();
user.__type = "Pointer";
user.className = "_User";
user.objectId = objectId;

string jsonUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

string url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AccountData?" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("where={\"user\":\"" + jsonUser + "\"}"); // this doesn't work
```

And the error I receive from the API is:

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid json: {\"user\":\"{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"_User\",\"objectId\":\"fvJ8jPjyjx\"}\"}"}
```

Comment: You need to pass a pointer object so your second attempt seems close. What does the resulting URL look like? I'm guessing a malformed URL is the issue.

Comment: sorry mate. yes, it's me again still on my adventures in parse land - have updated my question... see anything?

Comment: Have you tried to urlencoding only the jsonUser string instead of whole query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in building the URL. You're wrapping the JSON in a string and Parse is expecting an object. If you strip the double quote around jsonUser, I bet that'll work.

```
string url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AccountData?" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("where={\"user\":" + jsonUser + "}");
```

Comment: you are awesome! - want a job?